# How to install gpg without Admin password

Tags: macos, privacy, administrator, gpg

I have a monitored OS X laptop that I would like to put GNU Privacy Guard (gpg) on.  Of course I can't because I don't have Admin rights, but I was hoping there is a way to install it in user space through a virtual environment or chroot, or some other wizardry, or by exacting the package files.

Obviously I only need console access to the app.

Comment: Went ahead and made a hack using OpenSSL.  Something to play with until another option is available.  [Gist Repo](https://gist.github.com/brianddk/a22febdca28f79ad58b0)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is a feature that is available yet, as GPG does provide functions which require root access.  However, the issue appears to be on their radar as there exists a ticket.

See the ticket [here](https://gpgtools.lighthouseapp.com/projects/65162/tickets/158-allow-users-to-install-gpgtools-without-root-permissions)

And 3 forum posts have been tied to that ticket.

Comment: Sure.. the full GPG Tools suite would be awesome... but all I was looking for is `tar -xzvf SomeGpgBins.tar.gz`.  Looked at GPG4USB but they don't have OSX binaries.